# Logstash unable to receive data from MQTT

Tags: logstash, mqtt

Logstash unable to receive data from MQTT. Getting this from logs:

```
//Stack: C:/Users/Shah Zain/Downloads/logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.11.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/logstash-input-mqtt-0.0.2/lib/logstash/inputs/mqtt.rb:63:in block in run' C:/Users/Shah Zain/Downloads/logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.11.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/codecs/delegator.rb:64:in block in decode'
C:/Users/Shah Zain/Downloads/logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.11.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/logstash-codec-plain-3.1.0/lib/logstash/codecs/plain.rb:54:in decode' C:/Users/Shah Zain/Downloads/logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.11.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/codecs/delegator.rb:62:in block in decode'
org/logstash/instrument/metrics/AbstractSimpleMetricExt.java:74:in time' org/logstash/instrument/metrics/AbstractNamespacedMetricExt.java:68:in time'
C:/Users/Shah Zain/Downloads/logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.11.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/codecs/delegator.rb:61:in decode' C:/Users/Shah Zain/Downloads/logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.11.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/logstash-input-mqtt-0.0.2/lib/logstash/inputs/mqtt.rb:62:in block in run'
C:/Users/Shah Zain/Downloads/logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.11.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/mqtt-0.6.0/lib/mqtt/client.rb:392:in block in get' C:/Users/Shah Zain/Downloads/logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.11.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/mqtt-0.6.0/lib/mqtt/client.rb:424:in block in get_packet'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1586:in loop' C:/Users/Shah Zain/Downloads/logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.11.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/mqtt-0.6.0/lib/mqtt/client.rb:422:in get_packet'
C:/Users/Shah Zain/Downloads/logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.11.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/mqtt-0.6.0/lib/mqtt/client.rb:391:in get' C:/Users/Shah Zain/Downloads/logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.11.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/logstash-input-mqtt-0.0.2/lib/logstash/inputs/mqtt.rb:61:in run'
C:/Users/Shah Zain/Downloads/logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.11.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:414:in inputworker' C:/Users/Shah Zain/Downloads/logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64/logstash-8.11.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:405:in block in start_input'
[2023-11-22T09:32:55,314][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline ][main][f703af6384f6f11c9402520844f19db1b69aebf72a7dae8db7e841b01fe5b0ab] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
Pipeline_id:main
Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Mqtt topic=>"Application1/Message", id=>"f703af6384f6f11c9402520844f19db1b69aebf72a7dae8db7e841b01fe5b0ab", qos=>0, port=>1883, enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_0495dd43-938f-4077-9776-aeec7438618a", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, mqttHost=>"localhost", ssl=>false, client_id=>"logstash-mqtt-inputx5vl", clean_session=>true>
Error: undefined method `' for #LogStash::Event:0x76884d8d
Exception: NoMethodError
```

my config file:

```
input {
  mqtt {
    port => 1883
    topic => ["Application1/Message"]
    qos => 0
  }
}

filter {
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }

  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "test.logstash"
    user => "elastic"
    password => ""
  }
}
```

Troubleshooting Attempts:

I've checked the Logstash documentation and MQTT input plugin, but I couldn't find any discrepancies in the configuration. I also tried adjusting the configuration as per documentation, but the issue persists. Additional Information:

Logstash version: logstash-8.11.1-windows-x86_64